# Как найти минимальное значение?

Tags: perl

Есть массив `(100,-50,-25, 160)`. Подскажите пример, как выбросить все отрицательные числа из него и среди оставшихся найти минимальное?

Answer (score 6):

```
# perl -MList::Util=min -le 'print min grep { $_ >= 0 } @ARGV' 100 -50 -25 160
```

100

Answer (score 0):

```
my @a = (100, -50, -25, 160, 50, -3, 5);
my $min;
$_ < 0 ? () : !defined $min ? $min = $_ : $min > $_ ? $min = $_ : () for @a;
print $min; # 5
```

Сложность - O(n)